# WebRTC -- can getUserMedia use local stream?

Tags: html5-video, webrtc, h.264

I want to let WebRTC encoded and play h264(NAL) stream(local file).
In the WebRTC tutorial, getUserMedia is use for get local camera connecting to the system,  I don`t know if the getUserMedia function support
capture the local stream file like h264 stream.

If it doesn't work that way, may be I should modify WebRTC source code(I'm studying it). 
Here is the question, If i change WebRTC code, how can i integration the new code into browser? Made it a plugin?

Comment: Thank your for answer my question. I`ve found **[ffmpeg.js](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/ffmpeg)**   to transcode my file in mp4 so i can play on the web.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox supports an extension to the `<video>` element that you can use to do this.

First, set the source of a video element:

```
v1.src = "file:///...";
```

Then you can call the (currently prefixed) `mozCaptureStream` or `mozCaptureStreamUntilEnded` function to get a `MediaStream`.

```
stream = v1.mozCaptureStream();
```

The [proposed specification](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-fromelement/).

Note however that you need to ensure that the file is *same origin* with respect to the page.  The same origin rules for `file:///` are probably going to cause issues.  Otherwise your `MediaStream` isn't going to be accessible to you.  One way to ensure that is not to set the location directly, but to load the file using an `<input type="file">` element.

As noted in other answers, Firefox currently only supports the baseline profile of H.264.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are right `getusermedia` will not work for you. However, there are a couple of options.

1. Hack a stream together using RTCDataChannel. Breaking up the media stream and delivering each packet and then handling it on the client side.
2. [Take a look at this demo](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/Pre-recorded-Media-Streaming/) for precorded media streams. I do not believe that H264 is addressed but it could help you on your way(probably for Firefox only)
3. Use some sort of webrtc breaker/endpoint that is native to stream the file. I know specifically that others(including myself) have streamed H264 to Firefox through the [Janus-Gateway](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway)

Couple of asides:

- Firefox only supports Baseline profiles in streaming h264 for a webrtc peerconnection
- Chrome does not support h264 for webrtc at all

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to have getUserMedia *return* a h.264 encoded stream?

- In which case, today it will only be possible with Firefox today, under some specific environment (cisco 264 plugin installed) and only for the base profile.
- Chrome promised in november to add this capacity, but there is no timeline that I know of Expect at least Q2 2015.
- Using our (temasys) commercial plugin you will soon be able to do that in IE and Safari.

Those are the only options on client side I can think of. On server side you can use whatever you want to transcode, including janus, kurento, powermedia, licode/lynkia, ....

Note: using  other means like Datachannel or WebSocket are ok to transfer files, but would greatly reduce the user experience as you would not have all the added recovery (and security) mechanisms included in SRTP, DTLS, and would also not have specific mistreated media enhancements that are in webRTC like jitter, buffers, netQ, ect ...